# Chemical weapon to kill a werewolf

Tags: science-based, biology, chemistry, biochemistry

A weapon is needed for a climactic battle against an otherwise invincible wolf monster. In principle it could be any random thing, like the traditional silver, but we want something based in science. It should be a real chemical with actual biological properties, and something that takes effect fast enough to be used as a weapon.

#### Characteristics of the Chemical

An answer must be a real chemical satisfying the following requirements:

- **Secrecy** The chemical should not be present in everyday life in the real world, including both modern times and ancient times, or else it would be discovered too easily and the monster would never get a chance to be invincible. It cannot be in food or in the air in anywhere near the effective dose.
- **Effectiveness** The chemical needs to have some unusual biological effect when applied in the correct dose. This effect will serve to destroy the monster while nothing else available could, so it has to be something that cannot be achieved in any easier way. It should probably cause a loss of homeostasis in some biological system and that homeostasis can turn out to be critical to the monster's invincibility. The effect does not need to be harmful to real animals.
- **Nontriviality** The effect of the chemical should not be peripheral; removing the monster's hair or changing its color would never seem like a plausible way to destroy the monster's invincibility. Samson's weakness to having his hair cut is *not* a good example of the kind of weakness we're looking for.
- **Availability** The heroes need access to the chemical, so it either needs to be something that can be manufactured without sophisticated equipment, or it needs to be a chemical that is so stable that it could have survived for 300 years without climate control only to be discovered when it is needed. In this world there is nothing more advanced for doing chemistry than a typical kitchen, but in the past all sorts of advanced chemistry would have been possible.
- **Weaponizability** The chemical needs to be effective as a weapon, which means a small dose is enough. The ability to be absorbed through skin would be good, or it might be inhaled as fumes. If it could be effective by being coated onto an arrow, that would be excellent. It also needs to take effect quickly, ideally in less than a minute.

#### Characteristics of the Werewolf

The monster is a mammal that resembles a wolf, but it is the size of a tall and heavily built human and has a tendency to walk upright. Therefore answers that take advantage of either wolf biology or human biology are acceptable.

In spite of having real mammalian biology, the monster is a terror that overwhelms all other attempts to defeat it. There is some part of it that allows it to fight through any injury and recover from anything, but the exact mechanism is irrelevant. If we can find a suitable chemical, we can say that whatever organ or system is affected by the chemical is somehow critical to the monster's invulnerability. The chemical itself doesn't need to be deadly, since the monster can be killed by conventional means once its invulnerability is removed.

The monster's invulnerability has no effect on ways the chemical might be delivered. The monster's skin can be broken, and the monster cannot stop itself from breathing if the chemical must be inhaled. The monster has no special resistance to chemicals being absorbed through the skin.

Comment: /or it needs to be a chemical that is so stable that it could have survived for many years without climate control only to be discovered when it is needed./ - how many years?  10?  1,000?

Comment: I thought we weren't killing werewolves anymore. Aren't we supposed to send them to High School now?

Comment: Thermite, which will burn through the werewolf.

Comment: I take [Ricin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricin) is a bit too easy?

Comment: @JBH It can't be manufactured easily, but it's way more fun: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_trifluoride . It's so reactive that it can burn ash, sand and asbestos.

Comment: For the ultimate in "fun" use FOOF, which is so reactive it can make *ice* catch fire: https://infogalactic.com/info/Dioxygen_difluoride

Comment: What year is this story in? If it's something like the medieval ages, some stuff will not be available anyway. I get from the question that it seems like some post-apocalyptic world where technology to produce some stuff has been lost but not the actual products, is that correct?

Comment: Is this related to THNGW?

Comment: @JohnHamilton Yes, it is a future world where some technology that used to exist has been lost. The "Availability" section is intended to make that clear.

Comment: @Thucydides : FOOF just ever so slightly fails on the "so stable that it could have survived for 300 years without climate control" criterion - but it's still a fun idea ...

Comment: THIS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_trifluoride.  Don't ever get any near you though.

Comment: While I recognize that FOOF is not only unstable but also extremely difficult to synthesize, anything which can set *ice* on fire is obviously more than capable of taking out monsters as well....

Answer (score 72):

Killing the monster with VX nerve gas or an overdose of fentanyl or cyanide muffins seems kind of anticlimactic.  You can kill anything with that stuff.

The whole thing about werewolves is that silver is not predictably a super killer or especially bad for anything else.  It is a secret special Achilles heel for werewolves.  Except not so secret because it has been done to death.   Is there anything similar but novel we can use here?

**Chocolate.**  Chocolate is delicious (and keeps a long time).  Humans love it and dogs do too.  They will hog it all down if they get half a chance.   But everyone knows chocolate is to dogs as silver is to werewolves - [even a small amount can be lethal](https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/guide/dogs-and-chocolate-get-the-facts#1).   Symptoms include extreme thirst, too much energy, diarrhea, heart arrythmias, seizures and death.  I am picturing the SyFy channel: that is the way you want your monster to expend its last 5 minutes of show.

It might take longer than a minute for regular chocolate to kick in if some poor pooch gets hold of some.   Maybe in the story this is future chocolate - sort of like the super marijuana of today as compared to the hippie stuff of yesteryear.  To us: phenomenally good chocolate.  To canid monsters: INCONTINENT DEATH FRENZY!

Comment: Will... you're my hero!

Comment: Also onions can kill a dog. Grapes are bad too.

Comment: For the benefit of those who want to research this further, the problematic substance is *theobromine*, which in turn is found in cocoa. Since white chocolate contains rather small amounts of actual cocoa, you are better off with dark, "fine" chocolate -- or just isolate the active substance (theobromine, in this case) and somehow get the creature to consume large amounts of it. It's also worth noting that even dogs vary greatly in their sensitivity to theobromine; some are very sensitive, and others can consume a rather large amount with few ill effects. (Please, don't try it on your pooch!)

Comment: dude. You're a stronger man than me to not say... death by chocolate.

Comment: A werewolf having the size of an human, you'll need a stronger dose for it to work. Forget about regular chocolate, you'll have to make theobromine concentrate.

Comment: Never in a million years did I think this would have crossed anyone else's mind too, let alone that they would then have put it in an answer!  +1

Comment: What could help is that Werewolves are from European legend. (as far as I know) And chocolate is from the America's. So it even could be a new(ly discovered) substance to the users.

Comment: The catch here is that [chocolate's theobromine is actually poisonous to everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theobromine_poisoning). What makes it dangerous for dogs is they have far less body mass than a human. This means normal sized dogs have far less capacity to metabolize it out (humans metabolize many potentially poisonous chemicals, like caffeine, since the amounts are low). If we're talking about a  human sized dog then it might not harm the creature very much, if at all, unless it ate enough that would be fatal to a human (somewhere in the 10-20lb range).

Comment: Doesn't this go against the point "The chemical should not be present in everyday life in the real world, including both modern times and ancient times, or else it would be discovered too easily and the monster would never get a chance to be invincible."

Comment: Awe, I loved the cheekiness of this answer, all the science people are ruining it

Comment: @Machavity, human livers produce a substance that breaks theobromine down into harmless byproducts.  Wolf livers don't.  This is why a hundred-pound human can tolerate at least four times as much chocolate as a hundred-pound wolf.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek why go for the low-hanging fruit of "death by chocolate" when you can shoot for the moon with "INCONTINENT DEATH FRENZY" ?

Comment: On the same note, *caffeine* has the same issues for dogs as theobromine, and is generally more intense in its effects. Even better, most normal humans will have built a tolerance for it. Dissolved no-doz pills in some food would be pretty solid too.

Comment: Wow, this is very dark post... specifically, dark chocolate.

Comment: It doesn't match your requirements, but I wanted to mention suffocation by nitrogen.  Fun fact about our bodies - we don't actually have a method to detect when we're not getting enough oxygen.  Instead our bodies measure how much carbon dioxide we're breathing, and send a panic signal if we're getting too much.  But flood a room with nitrogen, and the people and werewolves inside will suffocate without ever knowing that they can't breath.

Comment: @Machavity well, even forcing a kilogram of chocolate down the throat of a wolf monster will be a bit hard. Though we could actually let him eat a few sheep that we fed with chocolate (the sheep will probably die though, before the werewolf kills them) and let him kill himself with that (if he's not a sophisticated monster).

Comment: And suddenly I have to ask: what would happen if Professor Lupin had a run-in with a Dementor? Let's feed him a Chocolate Fro - oh crap.

Comment: While the darker the chocolate is, the worse for the dog, there are many things far more poisonous to them.  According to the linked article it takes an ounce per pound of the dog for milk chocolate (no numbers for dark).  If you're talking a werewolf that size, it's going to be what, 500+ pounds?  Good luck getting it to eat 30 pounds of chocolate.

Comment: @sirjonsnow Surely the bigger the werewolf, the bigger the appetite, so it might quite well eat 30 pounds of chocolate if you had 30 pounds of chocolate.  Milk chocolate is usually only 20-25% cocoa solids, though, so if it was dark chocolate you'd only need a third as much, or you might be able to mix up cocoa powder with something.

Comment: @A.B. - you are definitely an individual to have back in the command tent, not up on the front lines.

Comment: Who said anything about front lines?  Leave chocolate on edge of village, watch fun from a (VERY) safe distance.

Answer (score 12):

#### Dimethylmercury

If I ever face a werewolf, I would personally try to poison it with a mercury derived toxin called **Dimethylmercury**. Here is why:

First of all, we all think that silver is a very good werewolf killer but maybe we are all wrong... The name of the real secret weapon against these beasts may have been lost through oral history, changing from Quicksilver to Silver... It is even plausible that a werewolf hidden organization (a powerful underground lobby) is at the base of the progressive name change from Quicksilver to the actual Mercury in order to erase all possibilities to find the true weapon!

Then, Mercury is not that difficult to find. Just go to the center of waste sorting of your nearby town and check for the “hazardous things” place. You should find what you need. The chemical reaction to transform Mercury in an even more dangerous toxin is pretty simple. Dimethylmercury for example, can be obtained with reagents “easily” stolen from any science university:

*Hg + 2 Na + 2 CH3I → Hg(CH3)2 + 2 NaI*

Concerning the Dimethylmercury effects, the werewolf will have to deal with **one of the strongest neurotoxins ever**, causing irreversible brain damages leading to mental confusion, memory issues, deafness and even blindness. I think all this will be enough to “finish him” quickly!

Another good point is how quick Dimethylmercury can find its way through the werewolf's skin and how difficult it is to be cured. Just look at the case of Karen Wetterhahn, a chemistry professor who died of accidental exposure to just a few drops of Dimethylmercury absorbed through her protection gloves!

[Wikipedia article on Karen Wetterhahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_Wetterhahn)

Quoting wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> Tests later revealed that dimethylmercury can, in fact, rapidly permeate different kinds of latex gloves and enter the skin within about **15 seconds**

So basically, if your werewolf doesn’t take a shower within 15 seconds, consider it as irremediably poisoned. Because yes, Mercury is a heavy metal, which makes it very difficult (almost nearly impossible) to remove it from a body.

---

#### Yes but…

There is one problem. Even if Dimethylmercury will poison the werewolf very quickly, symptoms will not appear before **several weeks** or months (for a human).

Of course, a solution would be to have your **werewolf metabolism to be very fast**, which could by the way explain its healing factor which is way above that of a normal living being... If your werewolf can recover from bullet injuries in a matter of days, then it is not unthinkable that its metabolism is at least 100 times faster (not sure about this calculus) than a human beings metabolism. From this we could imagine that Dimethylmercury assimilation by the body will occur in several hours. We are far from the minute you ask, but that’s the best I can do! :)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Cool answer. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: @Secespitus I think you missed all the **found**s in place of **find**s :p just thought this was funny since the answer was edited lol.

Comment: @shieldedtulip Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't have a lot of time when I was editing this answer before.  There were a few more things I fixed this time. If you find typos in posts on the site feel free to suggest an edit by clicking on the edit button. That's normally a lot faster than pinging another user and letting him find the things you already found. If you have less than 2k reputation it even gives you 2 reputation if your suggestion gets approved by users who have more than 2k reputation (that's the limit for the privilege to edit without needing approval).

Comment: Problem being that this is a rather potent toxin for people or anything with neurons, too.  So, sure, you can kill... well, just about anything with it, but if you'll end up too demented (or dead) to enjoy it.

Comment: @Secespitus Thanks a lot for editing my answer ! I tried my best to avoid mistakes but I'm French and it's sometime hard.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Sure you can poison anything with that but it's the werewolf fast metabolism that transform that slow poison into something violent.

Comment: @Freedomjail No problem. I am from Germany and know how hard it can be to write in a language that is not your mother tongue. Thanks for providing high quality content to the site! Looking forward to reading more from you.

Answer (score 11):

Silver nitrate may be your chemical.

Silver salts are easy to prepare (silver + nitric acid (one of the easiest to develop acids)). They were used in the 1800s to treat rabies, as an antiseptic, and as a way of sterilizing people (didn't work in the latter case), wart treatments. Used to stain proteins, so it can easily get around a body, unlike some chemicals. Also used in old fashioned photography, so there are lots of good excuses for the stuff to be lying around somewhere.

Comment: Additionally, silver nitrate causes burns and stains the skin in high concentrations. It also explodes in contact with ethanol (and I think excess nitric acid), so if you somehow got a lot of this on a werewolf's fur, then dumped a solution like that on it...

Comment: I was thinking colloidal silver hidden in a medic bag.

Comment: Upvoted. I'd like to add that I read one book where a guy who was being chased through a hospital managed to grab a tub of Silver bromide (AgBr) from the X-ray room and chuck it down the beast's gullet when it roared at him. From the description of what happened next, I think that would have killed all but the absolute oldest and strongest werewolf. Dart injectors like were used for that liquid sunlight stuff in the Underworld series might make for a safer (if less fast-acting) delivery mechanisim.

Answer (score 8):

If the monster can not be blown to smithereens with sufficient quantities of explosive (or a large keg of black powder full of iron nails), I guess the invulnerability mechanism has to be near to magic in nature.

So any traditional "antidote" to evil magic should work logically -- possibly in conjunction with an appropriate delivery method.

For example you could resurrect the myth of Baldr, who could not be harmed by anything except mistletoe. Say that there is some truth in there, but you still need to wound the monster with mistletoe and you *do not know* what component of mistletoe is actually the active ingredient, so just shooting an arrow drenched in the juice might have no effect.

So what you do is design a gun capable of shooting solidified (frozen?) ballistic pellets of pureed mistletoe. Or a powerful composite bow with frozen mistletoe arrows, which adds some complication (kitchen chemistry, no more) since you need a refrigerated quiver.

- Secrecy: check. Nobody thought of using mistletoe that way before.
- Effectiveness: check. Something in mistletoe acts as a poison, disabling the invulnerability mechanism which turns out to be the reason the werewolf form is capable of *existing* in the first place (there's something of the kind in *Bull God* by Roberta Gellis - the Minotaur is held together by a powerful spell by Poseidon. Remove the spell, and the body literally falls apart. You can't get much more effective than that.
- Nontriviality: see above.
- Availability: check. The typical kitchen (and weapons shop) ought to be enough.
- Weaponizability: see under Effectiveness.

Comment: One of the best lines from the movie *[Valkyrie](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Valkyrie_(film)#Colonel_Mertz_von_Quirnheim):* "Any problem on Earth can be solved with the careful application of high explosives."

Comment: @JBH Well, I suppose, except for "how do I make this computer application start working the way it's supposed to?"...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Threaten the programmer with explosives.

Comment: @user31389 The typical implementation would be by psychopatic axe murderer who knows where your kids go to school, though... :-)

Answer (score 6):

Based on your requirement, a werewolf is basically invulnerable until some foreign agent is introduced. By invulnerable we also mean that decapitation would slow the monster down, but it would be up and going as soon as it found its head, and lots and lots of fire would **hurt**, and likely make it slightly irritable, but that it would regenerate too fast for the fire to destroy it.

Well, there is wolfsbane ([Aconitum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aconitum)) which is highly poisonous to anyone, but not more so to werewolves, right? Their werewolf invulnerability would burn right through the poison, right? Well, it is called wolfsbane for a reason...

I agree with LSerni that such a high degree of invulnerability must be magical, or perhaps due to a deal made with a demon or something along those lines. So. 
In an ancient tome, buried in a tomb in an old monastery, might be found the secret to activating the mystical qualities locked in the wolfsbane.

**Secrecy**: The werewolf, if it has been around long enough, knows that the secret to its destruction is hidden somewhere, and is desperately looking to find and destroy it before it can be found and used against it (Or it may be instrumental in why practically all knowledge of this compound has been lost). Or it may have heard of it from its maker, but discounts it, or came into being after the last great werewolf outbreak and is entirely unaware of it.

**Effectiveness**: Wolfsbane is a very poisonous plant across all its varieties, but simple poison would be negligible to the werewolf in its invulnerable state. True, Aconite won't kill the werewolf. However, when correctly prepared and introduced into the werewolf's bloodstream, it serves to hamper the werewolf's supernatural regenerative abilities, or perhaps overwhelm it for a time, allowing the werewolf to be finished of through more traditional means.

**Non-triviality**: There is no outward sign that the werewolf has been affected by the wolfsbane. But taking a potshot at it, will cause it to fall down and bleed all over itself, the way it would do a normal person. The trick is to know when to take that shot.

**Availability**: Since there are over 250 species of Aconitum, finding a plant or two should not be too difficult, provided you are in the Northern half of the world, near a damp, mountainous area, or can get some brought in from such an area. Easy-peasy-lemon-squeezy.

**Weaponizability**: A little bit of wolfsbane will go a long, long way. You will need to break the werewolf's skin in order to introduce it into its system. I would say (but that would be your call, as this is all me), that ingesting it might give the werewolf a mild case of diarrhea, but not inconvenience it too much (and may tip your hand). In order for it to be effective, the werewolf must be cut with a blade treated with it, with a dart or arrow dipped in it, or even with a bullet soaked in it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with werewolves is that they supposedly can tolerate massive amounts of physical abuse as well as large amounts of poison and still survive. Not only that, they also heal from their injuries quickly. Whichever secret chemical is used, it will be a bit like Kryptonium, an invented weakness to make the Superman less boring. Hence the silver bullet for werewolves.

Instead of inventing an alternative to silver, a better idea would be to use a mechanism that affects all living beings. Every living organism on earth needs oxygen to turn chemical energy into mechanical energy. Oxygen deprivation will kill us all rather quickly. An animal that is particularly strong, consumes more oxygen than weaker counterparts that are the same size. Werewolves should be no exception. They probably need a lot of oxygen since they are so strong. You could theorize that oxygen deprivation levels which are tolerable for us humans would make werewolves faint or die. Carbon dioxide and carbon monoxide are generated by setting fire to things. This is, and has always been, easy to do. Those two gases are heavier than air and will replace oxygen if they are "poured" into e.g. a cellar. If a werewolf was lured into that cellar, he would become harmless, faint and eventually die.

Comment: By extension, you can use this same concept with H2O (aka drowning).  Trap it in an enclosed area and flood the place.

Comment: This also gives a great excuse to have a character sacrifice themselves as bait, but be rescued at the last second only to have been scratched or bitten without anybody noticing... until book two.

Comment: This makes sense for the "speeded-up metabolism" description.  It could heal all kinds of physical damage, and heal internal damage that poisons do as it occurs, before they have time to become a problem, but if it needs oxygen then going faster would just make matters worse.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the list of horribly dangerous chemicals...

### Hydrofluoric Acid

There are plenty of acids that are more dangerous than HF, but it would probably be significantly harder for your heroes to get their hands on [fluoroantimonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid), [triflic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triflic_acid) or the like.  And HF is plenty dangerous on its own.

From the Wikipedia article:

> In addition to being a highly corrosive liquid, **hydrofluoric acid is also a powerful contact poison**. Because of the ability of hydrofluoric acid to penetrate tissue, poisoning can occur readily through exposure of skin or eyes, or when inhaled or swallowed. Symptoms of exposure to hydrofluoric acid may not be immediately evident, and this can provide false reassurance to victims, causing them to delay medical treatment. Despite having an irritating odor, HF may reach dangerous levels without an obvious odor. HF interferes with nerve function, meaning that burns may not initially be painful. Accidental exposures can go unnoticed, delaying treatment and increasing the extent and seriousness of the injury. Symptoms of HF exposure include irritation of the eyes, skin, nose, and throat, eye and skin burns, rhinitis, bronchitis, pulmonary edema (fluid buildup in the lungs), and bone damage.
>
> **Once absorbed into blood through the skin, it reacts with blood calcium and may cause cardiac arrest. Burns with areas larger than 160 cm2 (25 square inches) have the potential to cause serious systemic toxicity from interference with blood and tissue calcium levels**. In the body, hydrofluoric acid reacts with the ubiquitous biologically important ions Ca2+ and Mg2+. Formation of insoluble calcium fluoride is proposed as the etiology for both precipitous fall in serum calcium and the severe pain associated with tissue toxicity. In some cases, exposures can lead to hypocalcemia. Thus, hydrofluoric acid exposure is often treated with calcium gluconate, a source of Ca2+ that sequesters the fluoride ions. HF chemical burns can be treated with a water wash and 2.5% calcium gluconate gel or special rinsing solutions. **However, because it is absorbed, medical treatment is necessary; rinsing off is not enough.** Intra-arterial infusions of calcium chloride have also shown great effectiveness in treating burns.

Emphasis mine.

Wikipedia also provides a quick how-to on where you an acquire some if you can't find any in the lab.

> Hydrogen fluoride is generated upon combustion of many fluorine-containing compounds such as products containing Viton and polytetrafluoroethylene (Teflon) parts. Hydrofluorocarbons in automatic fire suppression systems can release hydrogen fluoride at high temperatures, and this has led to deaths from acute respiratory failure in military personnel when a rocket-propelled grenade hit the fire suppression system in their vehicle.

---

Alternatively, if you are interested in lighting the werewolf on fire you can always go for [dioxygen difluoride](https://what-if.xkcd.com/40/).

Comment: Weaponizability of Hydrofluoric Acid is quite low. It is corrosive, it dissolves glass, can be stored in some kinds of plastic, but spills are deadly and plastic is not the strongest...

Comment: Every acid with F,H or O is cool on the paper. But no one really want to be involved with those. As you even talk about FOOF, I must told you FOOF is cool but if you can see how cool it is, you are too close.

Answer (score 2):

Poisoned blowgun or airgun darts. These could be doped with a wide range of poisons both natural and manmade. As a bonus the dart body could be made out of silver.

Naturaly occuring poisons that might be used can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_poison

Such as
tubocurarine, curarine, quinine, protocurarine and related alkaloids. Most frequently derived from the bark of Strychnos toxifera

Cardiac glycosides, such as Acokanthera (possessing ouabain), oleander (Nerium oleander), milkweeds (Asclepias), or Strophanthus, all of which are in the Apocynaceae family.

The black legged dart frog and various other poisonous species of frog.

Artificial organophosphate nerve agents might also be used such as those found here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_agent

Such as Dimethylheptylpyran and Sarin. Sarin as a liquid could be sealed in a very small thin glass ampule in the head of the dart which would break on impact. 
I believe some nerve agents are not that hard to make, although I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 2):

**Genetic manipulation**

The key to destroying a werewolf is its regeneration ability.  All living beings have cells that divide to provide new growth.  The werewolf has something like this except in overdrive - and its body somehow knows if an arm has been cut off so it can grow another one.

In humans, this cell division can produce a 'rogue' cell that also goes into overdrive, splitting and growing at great rates.  We call this disease cancer.

The key then, is to manipulate the werewolf's cell division either to give it an *extremely* fast replication rate or a very slow one.  Fast would cause cancer (as fast as you choose) and a slow one would make a werewolf susceptible to all other types of death.

By targeting the werewolf's regeneration genes other life on the planet *should* not be affected.

At some point in the past, werewolves were a big problem which is when this 'treatment' was developed.  For some reason, the werewolves went into hiding - maybe because they heard about it or some of them actually died from it.  Over another couple of hundred years werewolves became a legend and people largely forgot about them.  Those who were werewolves hid their affliction but one decided he was invulnerable and 'came out'.  The heroes recalled there was a something developed long ago and the quest began...

Answer (score 1):

Safely stored in the cold caves under a glacier in the North pass, lie the dart tips made by a rod of white Phosphorus covered by a layer of Gallium, the latter in the shape of a harpoon tip. The gallium melts after penetrating the skin.

Ensure that the shape is such that part of the Phosphorus will enter in contact with the air to facilitate self-ignition. Otherwise, provide a tip of Sodium (or Caesium, or Rubidium), still under the Gallium, for ignition as soon as it enter in touch with the aqueous environment under the werewolf skin.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_phosphorus_munitions#Effects_on_people

And if you want to add a poison that smells like garlic, and possibly related to it, you could encase a thin rod of Arsenic trioxide in the white Phosphorus. The arsenic will melt and boil as soon as the latter ignites. Internal contamination as well as inhalation are quite likely.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arsenic_trioxide#Toxicology

Comment: The above should badly damage just anything. If you want it to be specific to werewolves, you may need an alloy of gallium and some other material to raise the melting point to match the body temperature of the monster, which we can assume to be higher compared to that of a human being, much like a strong fever.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, [chilli powder works very well on elephants](https://www.livescience.com/55849-chili-powder-firecracker-condoms-scare-elephants.html) as a deterrent, so I daresay something a little more lethal, such as finely powdered silver wrapped in delicate bag with explosives inside could work in a similar (though much more deadly) and low-tech manner to this.

All of the elements are available, [silver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver#History) has been around for a millennium or two, and [China had gunpowder from the first century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunpowder#China).

Answer (score 1):

[Dimethyltryptamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citronella_oil)

- **Secrecy:** it has been used for centuries by shamans to talk to spirits, but it was only isolated quite recently in human history, and you will only have regular contact with it if you are a psychonaut.
- **Effectiveness:** the onset for injected DMT is less than a minute, and the effects may last up to 45 minutes (but usually they last up to 15 minutes) depending on dosage. During this time, the subject will be helpless.
- **Nontriviality:** The effect of this drug is that the subject will be enjoying a psychedelic, out-of-body experience.
- **Availability:** if your heroes are smart they may be able to isolate some from tree barks with highschool lab material. Or you can distill it from ayahuasca with kitchen material, though it won't be as concentrated as if you did use a proper lab.
- **Weaponizability:** as stated before, it takes less than a minute to kick in. You could coat arrows with it, but using something like a tranquilizer gun would be ideal. It can also be inhaled and the effects will be majorly the same, so you can use smoke as well.

Answer (score 1):

To go with the old silver, but with a twist:

**Dental amalgam**

a mixture of mercury, silver, tin and copper. Something that could be made with medieval-like technology and could also have been stored as old dentist´s supplies, found in old skeletons teeth or  in toxic waste disposals.

Could be delivered as power and possibly inhaled or molded onto other Weapons surfaces.

As we know, Silver reacts with the werewolf on contact. I imagine this will happen in a exothermic reaction, which will cause the mercury to vaporize.

The werewolf, already weakened from the silver, will then die of mercury poisoning.

Comment: Plot twist: werewolves are weak against bites from humans who have had their cavities filled.

Comment: @Renan: But remember to exhale sharply, our you´ll be the one with the mercury positioning problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a silver based gas that ends up in our atmosphere

**AgNP** , It's health affects on humans have been overlooked for quite some time so it is viable.

[Health Report](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.3155/1047-3289.60.7.770)

[How to synthesize](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783319112619-c2.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1494789-p176975801)

dump a whole lot of that in your area. Wont kill the humans, they wont even know what's happening till weeks later when people come down with asthmatic symptoms

surely if this is a werewolf it will have allergy to silver, and if it cant breath well you can do a whole lot of whatever you want to it.

Answer (score 0):

Antifreeze kills dogs. It's a real issue if you have something like a junk yard where it might leak from old cars.

Another option is to go to any pet web site and look for "shit that can kill your dog". A lot of food is not safe for dogs (chocolate, onions, garlic... list is pretty long).

Comment: I think antifreeze kills most things, it's just that only dogs are silly enough to drink it just because it smells vaguely sweet.  To be a serious threat I'd assume that a werewolf would have to not have the same blind spot as dogs about eating anything that stands still long enough.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like something that at least contains silver would be required to kill a werewolf. If traditional bullets and weapons are not up your alley, perhaps something more explosive and less expected, like silver fulminate. It is often used in "crackers" along with potassium chlorate, but is also used as a primary explosive. It is conceivable that a werewolf, expecting to be immune to a regular explosion, could be caught off guard by such an attack.

6,000 of these small explosives would be sufficient to do some serious damage to a werewolf, and could be triggered simply by being dropped from higher ground, as demonstrated in this video: https://youtu.be/tduhGmZHQGQ?t=72